# Comparing two strictly concave function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove something that seems very simple and intuitive but I cannot formalize a rigorous proof:

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: [0:1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions. Assume further that $f$ and $g$ are both symmetric around $\frac12$, i.e. $f(x) = f(1-x)$ and $g(x) = g(1-x)$.

We know the following: (i) $f(0) = g(0) = 0$, (ii) $f$ and $g$ are both strictly concave in $[0:1]$. (iii) $f$ and $g$ are both strictly positive in $(0,1)$, (iv) $f'(0) < g'(0)$, (v) $f'(1/2) = g'(1/2) = 0$ and finally (vi) $f(1/2) < g(1/2)$.

From the above conditions, I would like to conclude that $f(x) < g(x)$ for $\forall x \in (0,1)$. How, can this be done?

(I believe there is a very simple and basic proof but I cannot find it!).

P.S.: Let's assume $f$ and $g$ are analytic as well.

Comment: I think it's not true.  Imagine $f(x)=x(1-x)$.  Construct $g$ so that $g'(0)>1$, but quickly drops and stays almost constant so that $g$ is below $f$ at some point around $x=\frac{1}{4}$ but $f$ drops below again before $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample.

With $g(x) = x (1-x)$,
take $f_0(x)$ to be the polygonal curve with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1/3, 3/13)$,
$(2/3, 3/13)$, $(1,0)$, and "smooth it out" slightly: round the sharp corners and add a small multiple of $g$ to make it strictly concave.

Here are the graphs of $g$ and $f_0$.

[image]

EDIT: For an analytic example, let $f(x) = g(x) + \epsilon x (x - 1/5) (x - 2/5) (x- 3/5) (x - 4/5) (x-1)$ where $\epsilon > 0$ is sufficiently small:
I believe $\epsilon = 1$ works when $g(x) = x (1-x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I doubt if we require the functions to be analytic we could construct such a counterexample?

Comment: It's easy enough to imagine $$g''(x)=\left\{\begin{align} -\alpha & : x < x_0 \\ -\epsilon & : x_0 \le x \le x_1 \\ -\alpha &: x_1 < x < \frac{1}{2} \end{align} \right .$$ where $\alpha$ is large and $\epsilon$ is small, and build an analytic function from there.  (By "easy enough" I mean it will take a few minutes but it easy to imagine.)